# R: Apply a function over only character columns without type coercion

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many columns. The columns differ in their types: some are numeric, some are character, etc. Here's a small example where we just have 3 variables with 2 types:

```
# Generate data
dat <- data.frame(x = c("1","2","3"),
                  y = c(1.0,2.5,3.3),
                  z = c(1,2,3),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to replace the value 3 with a space, but only for character columns. Here's my current code:

```
out <- as.data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) { 
                                              ifelse(is.character(x), 
                                              gsub("3", " ", x), 
                                              x)}), 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The problem is that the ifelse() function ignores that y and z are numeric and that it also seems to coerce the numeric variables to character anyway.

And idea has been to pull out the character columns, gsub() them, then bind them back to the original data frame. This, however, changes the ordering of the columns. Key to any solution is that I do not need to specify variables by name but only by type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can also do this trivially using dplyr:

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Create data
dat <- data.frame(x = c("1","2","3"),
              y = c(1.0,2.5,3.3),
              z = c(1,2,3),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Replace 3's with spaces for character columns
dat <- dat %>% mutate_if(is.character, function(x) gsub(pattern = "3", " ", x))
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and for me it seems like `ifelse` did not work but separating `if` ad `else` does. Below is the code which works:

```
# Generate data
dat <- data.frame(x = c("1","2","3"),
                  y = c(1.0,2.5,3.3),
                  z = c(1,2,3),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> lapply(dat, function(x) { if(is.character(x)) gsub("3", " ", x) else x })
$x
[1] "1" "2" " "

$y
[1] 1.0 2.5 3.3

$z
[1] 1 2 3

> as.data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) { if(is.character(x)) gsub("3", " ", x) else x }))
  x   y z
1 1 1.0 1
2 2 2.5 2
3   3.3 3
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I've produced an answer with a dplyr solution below as well.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to this line in `?ifelse`

> `ifelse` returns a value **with the same shape** as `test` ...

`is.character` is length one so the returned value is length 1. You can use `if(...) yes else no` as you have suggested instead as @Heikki have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @user3614648 solution:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, funs(ifelse(. == "3", " ", .)))

x   y z
1 1 1.0 1
2 2 2.5 2
3   3.3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

### dplyr >= 1.0.0

Scoped verbs that end in `_if`, `_at`, `_all` have been superseded by the use of [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) in `packageVersion("dplyr")` 1.0.0 or newer. To do this using `across`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat |>
    mutate(across(where(is.character), \(x) replace(x, x == "3", " ")))
```

### purrr

```r
library(purrr)

# using a predicate function
dat |>
  modify_if(is.character, \(x) replace(x, x == "3", " "))

# by location
dat |>
  modify_at(1, \(x) replace(x, x == "3", " "))
```

Comment: Note: this uses the base R pipe `|>` and shorthand anonymous function syntax `\(x)` introduced in R 4.1.0.